Problem with http requests in docker container with ASP.NET Core 8.0
I have an ASP.NET Core 8.0 application running in a docker container on ubuntu 22.04 server. The problem is that when I make an http request (post/get) I get no response from the remote server, I get a 504 timeout exception.
I'm using MailKit and sending an email using the SendAsync method,  but if I use IHttpClientFactory and HttpClient, the same error will occur.
When I run the application locally on Windows, I can send any request and the remote server responds.
When I make a request using curl from the server command line, I get a 200 response.
When I make a request from the container to install curl, it can't download it.
I already had this problem with another container, but I used network_mode: host in docker-compose.
I configured dns in docker-compose but it didn't help.
Dockerfile:
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS base
#USER app
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 8081

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["SwishLeadplace/SwishLeadplace.csproj", "SwishLeadplace/"]
COPY ["SwishLeadplace.BusinessLogic/ClassLibrary1/BusinessLogic.csproj", "SwishLeadplace.BusinessLogic/ClassLibrary1/"]
COPY ["SwishLeadplace.BusinessLogic.Core/BusinessLogic.Core/BusinessLogic.Core.csproj", "SwishLeadplace.BusinessLogic.Core/BusinessLogic.Core/"]
COPY ["SwishLeadplace.DataAccess/SwishLeadplace.DataAccess/SwishLeadplace.DataAccess.csproj", "SwishLeadplace.DataAccess/SwishLeadplace.DataAccess/"]
COPY ["SwishLeadplace.Shared/SwishLeadplace.Shared/SwishLeadplace.Shared.csproj", "SwishLeadplace.Shared/SwishLeadplace.Shared/"]
RUN dotnet restore "./SwishLeadplace/SwishLeadplace.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/SwishLeadplace"
RUN dotnet build "./SwishLeadplace.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
RUN dotnet publish "./SwishLeadplace.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "SwishLeadplace.dll"]

Docker-compose:
services:
  leadplace_service:
    image: leadplace_service:latest
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3333:8080"
      - "3332:8081"
    environment:
      ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT: "Development"
      ASPNETCORE_URLS: "http://+:8080"

I think this is only found in containers with ASP.NET Core, because I am running a container with Seq logger and there is no problem there.
